# Why does the inputmode attribute on input elements not present me with a virtual keyboard as the MDN documentation describes?

Tags: html

The [`inputmode`](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/HTML5/examples/attribute-inputMode.html) attribute has no effect in any of the popular browsers as described in [this document on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-inputmode) in that it presents no virtual keyboard.

I reproduce the code snippet here:

```
<html>
    <label for = "txtName">Name</label>&nbsp;<input name = "txtName" type = "text" inputmode = "text" /><br />
    <label for = "txtAge">Age</label>&nbsp;<input name = "txtAge" type = "text" inputmode = "numeric" /><br />
    <label for = "txtEmail">Email</label>&nbsp;<input name = "txtEmail" type = "text" inputmode = "email" /><br />
    <label for = "txtUrl">Url</label>&nbsp;<input name = "txtUrl" type = "text" inputmode = "url" /><br />
    <label for = "txtPhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>&nbsp;<input name = "txtPhoneNumber" type = "text" inputmode = "tel" /><br />
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=inputmode), this isn't supported by default in any of the major browsers. So today it won't have any effect. It looks like support is coming though - Firefox has a flag to enable it, Chrome has it marked "in development", and Edge says it's"under consideration".

Comment: I guess then I can write it off as one of the hundreds of HTML5 features that are slow in coming.

Comment: Funny, 10 days after this question was asked caniuse.com was updated to say support is coming in Chrome v66: https://caniuse.com/#search=inputmode

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is used only for mobile phones to chose which type of keyboard to display.

As [this](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/23-inputmode.html) article states: The inputmode attribute tells the browser on devices with dynamic keyboards which keyboard to display. The inputmode attribute applies to the text, search and password input types as well as .
This attribute is only relevant in browsers on devices that have dynamic keyboards.

Comment: Thank you. It is surprising that the most authoritative document on HTML5, the WHATWG living document (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/interaction.html#attr-inputmode) does not qualify that this attribute is meant for mobile devices only. It generalizes by saying that it is for all user-agents. However, what you are saying does appear to be right.

Answer (score 0):

> This attribute is only relevant in browsers on devices that have dynamic keyboards.

"inputmode" just hints the browser which virtual keyboard to display, it doesn't enables the virtual keyboard. On touch screen mobiles and laptops it should work and display the correct keyboard(on most devices, not guaranteed on all devices).
 While for other PCs you can try some virtual keyboard extension such as [Google Input Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en), but again its not guaranteed to work.
Also for telephone, email and url use

```
<input type="tel">
<input type="email">
<input type="url">
```

for better support on various devices and browsers.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the new input elements you listed. However, their support is also not yet implemented properly on all browsers. Appearance wise, they all downgrade gracefully to `type = text` where they are not supported. But I digress.

Comment: True, use `type` or `inputmode` it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you pick that first line (blockquote) of your answer from? Can you please leave an attribution?

Comment: "https://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/23-inputmode.html", not the best place to quote something from, but what they say is absolutely correct so I quoted it.